How to make a post inside a group using LinekdIn API
In shot I am trying to create a post inside a group on linkedIn.
I have managed to pass 3-legged authentification, I have access token, and I can get userId by using endpoint /v2/userinfo. Besides that I have managed to create a post on my profile, but I cannot find any documentaion on how to create a post inside group.
Oauth scopes that my app has are: openid, email, profile, w_member_social.
So if you know, please let me which endpoint, or key I should use to make a post inside a group.
I have tried many things that I have found in other threads here like adding containerEntity req body, but I either get error that body is not good or that: "Author  does not match Company"

I have made a research for this, I have even opened ticked on linkedIn developers portal and they said to me that for security reasong there is no option to post inside linkedIn groups with their API, only linkedIn parters maybe could do that.
So to summarise: Its not possible to post inside linkedIn groups with their API.
